# How to use IVsPackageSourceProvider provider

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, visual-studio-extensions

How to use `IVsPackageSourceProvider` can I get a list of NuGet sources, like a `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`? I try to use just such a structure:

```
   using (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider provider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)base._dteObject))
    {

        IComponentModel service = (IComponentModel)provider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        try
        {
            var sourceProvider = service.GetService<IVsPackageSourceProvider>();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

But `Try` block raises an `Exception` with the text:

> Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type
>   'NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageSourceProvider
>   (ContractName="NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageSourceProvider")' to type
>   'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageSourceProvider'

Please tell me how to use this provider.

*Sry for bad english*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of packages NuGet via IVsPackageInstallerServices, like this:

```
try
            {
                //Using the IComponentModel service
                var componentModel = (IComponentModel)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));

                //var sourceProvider = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageSourceProvider>();

                IVsPackageInstallerServices installerServices =
                    componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerServices>();


                var installedPackages = installerServices.GetInstalledPackages();



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

Edit:

[image]

Code:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDe3a-mSTWubSix-w

Comment: Thanks for answer! but, i want get sources of NuGets from Visual Studio, not packages. Sorry for wrong question.

Comment: the code seems ok, I create the demo with visual studio 2015, .Net framework 4.6, it works,

Comment: I understood. It just does not work in Visual Studio 2013. Thank you for help!